# how to refresh Joomla token in form by AJAX

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax, security-token

I've got a website that uses an AJAX call to login a user. To secure this, I've added a token to the login form - https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms

**the problem is that, when the user is inactive for a while, the Joomla auto logout is fired. And therefor my token dosen't work.**

How do I refresh the token by AJAX before making the login call?

**----------------------------------------------------- More details: -----------------------------------------------------------**

The normal operation of the form is omitted in AJAX by:

```
jQuery('#login-user').click(function(e){            
e.preventDefault();
```

And then the login AJAX call is send:

```
form = jQuery('#userForm'); 

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?option=com_content&format=ajax&view=article&task=loginUser&tmpl=component',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        form: jQuery(form).serializeArray()
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(response){
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        if ( result.loggedIn == 1 ) {                       
            //User logged in
            jQuery('#loginModal').modal('hide');
            window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;// reload page creates a history entry
        }
        else {                  
            //User not logged in    
            console.log("not");         
        }               
    }
});
```

BUT: the problem is that, when the user is inactive for a while, the Joomla auto logout is fired. And therefor my token dosen't work.

How do I refresh the token by AJAX before making the login call?

Comment: So this isn't just about "securing ajax calls", this is "How do I perform an ajax call for a logged in user while passing a token AND when the user's session has expired, offer a re-login popup, then after re-logging in, the token must be refreshed and the initial ajax operation should be re-engaged?" Golly, this is certainly a reasonable desire, but definitely a complex thing to answer.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa! I see what you mean. Next time I´ll split it op in different questions that makes more sense that way.

Comment: Unfortuntely, questions that are Too Broad are either 1. not completely answered or 2. require a massive, comprehensive write up.  The first is a real let down for googlers who thinks they've struck gold in the search results only to find that there isn't a full answer available.  The second is simply too much reading for the average researcher.  Both are better than nothing, but to make JSE spectacularly valuable, we should all endeavor to make the site clean, comprehensive, searchable, and clear.

Comment: @mickmackusa I get what you see, I’ll update the question soon!

Comment: @mickmackusa The question is updated now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to answer your earlier question about this yesterday, but someone was already answered this partially for you. So according to me your original Login Form token field should be a bit changed like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="userForm">
    <label for="username">Brugernavn</label>    
    <input type="text" value="" name="username">    
    <label for="password">Password</label>  
    <input type="password" value="" name="password">
    <?php echo '<input id="token" type="hidden" name="' . JSession::getFormToken($forceNew=true) . '" value="1" />'; ?>

    <button id="login-user">Login</button>
</form>
```

This way the token function forced to generate always a new token which could be sent with the AJAX query anytime (your original AJAX query might be changed a bit too to forward the token created this way and checking the token in your called function should may be re-formulated too. Maybe those are OK as they are now, you'll test it). I hope this can help you in the question.

**Now the above solution is generating a new token for the Form only when the site is refreshed.** and that is not what you are looking for, as we found out a bit later. And I will not leave this subject without closing it if we went into this now.

**So, what is the real problem here?**

Of course as we talked about it (in the added comments), you could get a fresh token with an initial AJAX call to a function of **refreshingToken()** (which would be a custom function you could create with few lines of codes). But this function would also delete the old request/session token and would create a new one (and that would also mean a new session and new request). This is due to security reasons.

***Here is the problem and the most possible solution of what you want to accomplish:***
The real solution to your problem is about sessions and not about getting new tokens.

After you explained finally that you want to solve the problem of the logged in User when he is i.e. editing an article and it takes a little longer time for him to finish the editing, and this user has gotten logged out by the system, then you want them to be logged in again without redirection and losing their unfinished article for example.

**A working solution of this problem is how Joomla solved it with keeping the session alive with a core Joomla function.**

So if you call the following function at the top of your particular pages’ layout files (or in your Form layout file):

```
JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
```

Then It will just keep the user's session alive and that’s it, your problem is solved (we can say), since the session will not expire on the article editing page. The user will not lose his work as he won’t be logged out during an important article writing, editing.

**Now, do you have to create your own AJAX based login form to add keepalive() function to the com_content article edit page for example?**

No, you do not.

**KEEPING THE SESSION ALIVE ON DIFFERENT PAGES OF JOOMLA**

In Joomla, at the top of the **login module (mod_login)** the **JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');** is included, thus if you publish this login module on the Article Edit pages (or menus) for example, then the user session will be kept alive on those pages, so it means that your editor User will not lose his work, since he will not be logged out of his session, since the keepalive() function (via a javascript function) will refresh his session's time regularly.

**And finally**

If you still want to, you can also include **JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');** on the top of your custom Login Form layout file placed on the 'article edit' page and that will prevent of loging users out during editing and of losing an unfinished article at the side of your User.

**Another possible solution:**

1. You could also create a plugin which shows a remaining session time on article edit pages in a module and there could be a button to restart the session or fork the session. The Joomla/CMS/Session/Session class has functions for that which could be called (it should be studied more by myself too). So the user instead of logging in just can push a button to restart the session. *(later edit: I have checked these Session functions and unfortunately start(), restart(), fork(), all of these functions destroy the current session, so these are not working solutions of the problem in question).*

I am sorry for the very long description but this was the only way to clear the problem and the subject at an acceptable level. I hope this is gonna clear the subject more and will help you.

Comment: Thanks!!... Would this mean that, when a user is auto logged out, I have to to first make an AJAX call to fetch the new token and then afterwards do my login AJAX? :)

Comment: No, I do not think so. First just change your Form token field the way I wrote up here and then use what you already have. The point is that the Form at submit always have to create a new token for the new request cycle (that way there is no such thing as invalid token in that cycle because the token is always fresh with the new request). It is theoretically that simple and Joomla already has a solution for that (as it is given in the Form above).

Comment: So again clear it:
1. You have a Form.
2. You have the AJAX call.
3. You have the function which checks the token and log the user in.

Comment: Thanks!! I’ll try it out and let you know the result

Comment: Hmmm. I can't get this to work. Only if the page is reloaded it will work :/ ...The token is only refreshed on a page reload, so when I fire the AJAX call when the user is auto logged out by Joomla but the page haven't reloaded, then the token is the same and will be denied

Comment: Yes, I see the issue. There is a strong and valid security consideration behind the concept of session tokens and the creation of them (why and how to be secure). So let's understand a little more the task, the mechanism and the purpose what you really want to accomplish here (then I'll update my answer with additional possible solutions regarding this question). So we always have a fresh token but only by refreshing the page. We continue from here then... :)

Comment: I must face that what I wanted is not possible, because I don't want the page to reload. Will you edit your answer to that it's not possible because the page needs to refresh to make a new token? :) then I will mark your answer as accepted

Comment: No, I think what you want is absolutely possible, but you should then really make another initial AJAX call to refresh the token. But this invokes again security considerations and the question of logic and purpose about why you want a person to log into your user area ie. every second hour without even refreshing the site? With that consideration you can keep a person logged in with longer session times for example, you see... So the subject starts to be another subject...

Comment: Okay. The reason is that the user can write notes in a text field and then save it. The save button sends a AJAX to a saving function... therefore if it takes so long for the user to write the note that they get logged out, I don’t want them to loose their note by redirecting the page, but instead I want to show a login form that log them in again and make it possible to continue on the note and save it

Comment: Your original question was (before you edited), how to get valid token (yesterday), then how to get always fresh and valid token for login. Then the question was reformulated and now the question is "how to get an always fresh, secure, valid, user token without even refreshing the site?" You see, your purpose now looks like a moving target :) But usually I have the same when I am working on my projects, so it's not a problem for me...

Comment: I see that. Sorry for the confusion!! :(

Comment: Auto saving users comments, writings, I think should be solved with other solutions, not with logging the users in without refresh.

Comment: Thanks you so much for taking you time to help me out! Great answer!! got it to work now :)

Answer (score 4):

Playing with the sessions is usually not a very safe thing to do - you could create more problems by trying to find a solution.

You can do one (or both) of the following:

- Increase the Session Lifetime under `System`, `Global Configuration` to a higher number, such as 1440 (1 day). This will minimize the problem, but will not eliminate it. Another problem with this approach is that you may risk flooding your session table if your website gets a huge amount of traffic. See [here](https://www.itoctopus.com/a-flooded-session-table-can-dramatically-slow-down-your-joomla-site).
- Add, to your template, an Ajax request that will subtly load any page on your website every 30 minutes or so.

The previous answer mentions using `JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');`, which should also technically work, but I do remember (and I might be wrong) that it doesn't work well when page caching is enabled.

Comment: I agree with you that setting longer session time would be the simplest solution to this problem. JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive'); had issues but only when progressive caching was set on Joomla. But in that case there were problems with other javascript invoked functions at the same time.